# How can I fix formula cells in bulk? Excel

Tags: excel, formula, bulk

So I have a table of cells in excel that have loads of formulas referencing cells above it.

I want to create a copy of this table below it, and keep all the formulas and its values exactly the same. However when creating those formulas I didn't put $ to fix each cell. I dont want to go into each cell and add the $ to all cells before pasting.

Is there some way I can highlight the cells and bulk fix all the cells being referenced?

Thanks in advance, let me know if im not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use VBA:

Put this in a Module, select your range of cells, and run it.

```
Sub abslt()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        If rng.HasFormula Then
           rng.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(rng.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsolute)
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

It will convert all references to absolute references.

Comment: How do your coworkes find you a necessary evil if you never do any work =P

Comment: @findwindow that's the problem I do the work in half the time they do.  So I try to slow myself down a little.

Comment: `half the time` meaning 1/1000th =P